# smart pointer in function

Tags: c++, function, smart-pointers

Today I got problem with passing std::unique_ptr into function/overloaded operator. For instance:

```
    HEADER
class SpaceMarine{
   public:
        ...
        friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &exit, const SpaceMarine &SM);

   private:
       std::string name_; 
       .... (some other few parameters)
       std::unique_ptr<armor> armor_;
```

And in .cpp I got:

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &exit, const SpaceMarine& SM){ 

    exit << ... << *SM.stats_ << !!!!!! << *SM.weapon_; 
    return exit; 
}
```

stats_ and weapon_ are both classes that are members of the main class via pointers.
For all classes their own overloaded operators >> and << works ( meaning - when I simply write:

```
std::cout << armor1;
or
std::cin >> weaponb;
```

they work).

So : what do I have to put in place of !!!!!! , for unique_ptr to work in similar way to *SM.stats_? So it points to the overloaded operator of the armor class and uses it in overloaded operator of main class?

EDIT

For MikeSeymour :

```
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &exit, const Armor& arm){
    return exit << "\n" << arm.name_ << "  AR: " << arm.toughness_;
}
```

but, as I wrote before - the overloaded operators for member classes (Armor, Weapon) work.

Comment: A smart pointer can be used just the same as a normal pointer, so doing e.g. `*armor_` will work the same if it's a "normal" pointer or a smart pointer. See e.g. [`std::unique_ptr::operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*).

Comment: So is it `armor` or `Armor`? Do you have two differnt types, or is one a copy/paste error? The question would be easier to answer if you gave a complete (but small) example to demonstrate exactly what goes wrong when you try to output `*armor_`, and the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

You should simply derefence it (probably check before, that it is valid).

```
exit << ... << *SM.stats_ << *SM.armor_ << *SM.weapon_;
```

Comment: @WarmasterMazuran it can not work only and only if your `operator <<` for armor expects non-const reference as second parameter.

Comment: @Till: error is:
error: cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'|
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>;

I think it is something ForEveR is mentioning

Comment: @WarmasterMazuran: Perhaps you could post the overload of `<<` for `armor`. That seems to be the problem.